# What types of climate would form under set conditions?

Tags: geography, climate, map-making

The continent is located on the **Earth-like planet**.

The first map depicts a rough Köppen classification (which is there to give you bit of a context).

**Note** that:

1. Types 13 and 14 are undefined/placeholders, only marking the altitude.
2. **Edit:** The coast of the area in question (painted black) is subjected to El Niño–Southern Oscillation.
3. Marked prevailing winds function the same way Earth's winds do. *(Compare to map no. 4)*

**The area in question is the south-eastern chunk of land, painted in black.**

[image]

The next one is an altitude map, which is fairly obvious.

[image]

The Earth's Köppen classificaiton map, for comparison. **Note** that I used different colouring.

[image: koeppen scheme]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Köppen_climate_classification#/media/File:Köppen-Geiger_Climate_Classification_Map.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification#/media/File:K%C3%B6ppen-Geiger_Climate_Classification_Map.png)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**

Marked the prevailing winds on the first map.

Restructured the question a bit, added the map of Earth's prevailing winds.

Added sources:

- Worldbuilding: How To Design Realistic Climates, by Artifexian (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lCbxMZJ4zA& and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fag48Nh8PXE&)
- Climate of India, by vnperceptions (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAMPJyOY34s&)

Comment: Video was long!  I added key for Koeppen system from wikipedia

Comment: It was just one of many in the series. I will post links as sources, if need be. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It will be wet.**

3 and 4 above your mountains. are BSK and BWK, which are semi-arid and desert.  I conclude they are in the rain shadow of the mountains which means the prevailing winds are from the south.  So these winds have dropped their moisture on the other side of the mountains, which is the area you are interested in.

You could make your flat plain be oceanic (Cfb) on the coast, grading into humid subtropical (CFa) and then rainforest (Af) as the altitude increases and clouds drop their rain.  Maybe a band of CWC subtropical highland before your altitude gets really high.

---

As regards prevailing wind, I think of islands like Hawaii.  Maybe your island is more of a continent.  Check out the one big arrow for the prevailing trade winds; Kona wind is a lesser and occasional wind.  The high altitude in the middle of these islands combined with the moisture laden trade winds means there is a wet side and a dry side of each island.

http://www.sandwichislands.com/Graphics/rainfall.jpg

[image]

Comment: I've added prevailing winds to the map, to avoid confusion. Please check to see if your conclusion about the winds matches the new info.

Comment: Maybe I have not looked at enough maps of prevailing winds.  Your arrows look like they pointing right at each other!  When I think of an island and prevailing winds I think of arrows going the same direction.  Something like this:  http://www.sandwichislands.com/Graphics/rainfall.jpg.  Some maps, in addition to the trade winds (single big black arrow here) include more minor and occasional winds.